# How to filter by 2 or more conditions using R summarise?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

For the following data frame

```
    df <- data.frame(identifier = c("A","B","C),
                     age = c(33, 65, 42), 
                     sex=c("male", "female","male"))
```

I want to be able to filter and count the number of males over 60, however this does not work:

```
summary <- df %>% summarise(males_over_60 = sum(age>60[sex=="male"]))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are no males aged > 60 in your example data. I also edited your code to add closing parentheses which were missing, and to make age a numeric variable.

Comment: You could use `&`, e.g. `df %>% summarise(males_over_60 = sum(age > 60 & sex == "male"))` should work as expected

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by @neilfws, no rows in your example data satisfy both conditions.

However, using `mtcars` as an example, you can filter on two conditions using `&`:

```
mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 4 & hp >100)
```

```
              mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt qsec vs am gear carb
Lotus Europa 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.9  1  1    5    2
Volvo 142E   21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.6  1  1    4    2
```

and you can summarise this as you like.